Reduce intensity (luminosity) of Apple Studio Display
I find Apple's Studio Display to be far too bright, and after a while of using it, my eyes feel quite strained.
Turning down the Brightness control just makes things darker, but seemingly still as 'intense'.
Only when I bought a second (different) display, did I realise how bright it was by comparison, and I want to make the two displays similar.
So I'm looking for a way to reduce the overall intensity of the screen.

Hidden away in System Settings > Displays, there is a drop-down menu for "Presets". In earlier OSes, you could select a "Color Profile", which was a color management profile, but presets are a bit different.

If you select "Customize Presets", you can create a new preset, using the + button, which is based on the currently selected preset.

The preset configuration includes a setting that limits the luminosity of the screen. Apple's advertised value of 600 nits can be brought down to 300 or even lower. (Some of the bundled presets for Photography or Print are set at 160 nits.)
The "Maximum Luminance" value sets the screen intensity, in nits.

Apple has some documentation on the presets here and here.
I've noticed that once you set a custom preset, the Brightness and Auto-adjust Brightness settings are locked.
The five people who understand color management may have more to add.
